# The popup control doesn't open-up when using .exe from WPF but runs in VS 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, exe

I have a popup in my application which is activated by a change in selected value of a combobox.
It works fine when I debug in VS 2010 but it doesn't fire when I use the .exe on the same computer.

Is there an additional property of the popup I should use to make it stay on when using .exe?

```
 private void trigger_mode_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MODE = trigger_mode.SelectedValue.ToString();
        switch (Convert.ToString(trigger_mode.SelectedValue))
        {
            case "triggerModeData":
                Popup_data.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Mouse;
                Popup_data.StaysOpen = false;
                Popup_data.Height = 200;
                Popup_data.Width = 250;
                Popup_data.IsOpen = true;
                break;

            case "triggerModeRepeat":
                Popup_repeat.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Mouse;
                Popup_repeat.StaysOpen = false;
                Popup_repeat.Height = 200;
                Popup_repeat.Width = 250;
                Popup_repeat.IsOpen = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

XAML code

```
 <Popup x:Name="Popup_repeat" AllowsTransparency="True">
        <StackPanel Background="BurlyWood">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Name ="T1" Text="Please enter the time interval between triggers in milliseconds"/>
            <TextBox Name="T2" Text="Enter value here" KeyDown="T2_KeyDown"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    Detail - In the trigger repeat the camera is triggered periodically with a specific time interval.
                    Please enter the time between each triggers in the textbox above by first deletign the line 'Enter value here'
                    and put the time interval value in milliseconds.
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
    <Popup x:Name="Popup_data" AllowsTransparency="True">
        <StackPanel Background="BurlyWood">
            <TextBlock Name ="T3" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Please enter the time to wait after trigger in milliseconds."/>
            <TextBox Name="T4" Text="Enter value here" KeyDown="T4_KeyDown"/>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    Detail - In the data trigger mode the camera waits a certain time after a mechanical pre-trigger and 
                    then sends a trigger to the camera to take a picture after that interval. If you are using this mode. 
                    Enter the time the camera has to wait after the trigger in teh textbox by first deleting the text 
                    'Enter value here' and thentype in the interval time in milliseconds"
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock> 
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't open at all?  Perhaps it opens and immediately closes because of a focus change.  Try changing `StaysOpen` to `True` to see if the popup ever appears in the running executable.

Comment: I dont understand what focus change is but I'll try changing StaysOpen to true.

Comment: Ohh, I get it, focus change is when the debugging goes back to mainwindow from popup, and does the .exe file in the bin folder gets rebuilt after each debug operation or do I have to do something else to save any changes from code in .exe?

Comment: Here are some good reads on WPF Focus: [Focus and Activation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/09/wpf-in-visual-studio-2010-part-3-focus-and-activation.aspx), [The curious world of WPF Popups](http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.com/2011/08/curious-world-of-wpf-popups.html).

Comment: Not sure I follow your question about code changes and the .exe.  If you compile your code, it will take all the current code and build the executable.  You can make changes while debugging using Edit and Continue, and it will capture those changes, but you'll need to recompile before those are included in the compiled executable.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. The code works fine now and the .exe fires the popup and it remains open till I get the input. Thanks again.

Comment: I've added an answer below with the solution that seems to have worked for you.  Please accept it so that others can discover the solution if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the popup to remain open to receive input, you'll need to set the `StaysOpen` property to `True`.  Otherwise, the popup will close as soon as focus or activation leaves the popup.